# C#: ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled by usercode

Tags: c#, forms, listbox

I have an if statement saying that if a webpage has a certain text to remove the selected item on a listBox and iterate down to the next one.

I made some code but when I try it I keep getting:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled by usercode

This is the error in more detail:

> {"InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for
>   'SelectedIndex'.\r\nParameter name: SelectedIndex"}

This is my code:

```
        listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = + 1;
```

EDIT:

Thanks for all the help guys! I removed the issue by not removing the items and just making it iterate down.

Comment: how many items are in your listbox? why do you set the SelectedIndex to 1? If you remove the last item you should not set it to 1. There have to be at least two items left.

Comment: `listBox1.SelectedIndex = + 1` is the same as doing `listBox1.SelectedIndex = 1`.

Comment: @slfan I was testing it out with two items in my list

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel So I should change it to that?

Comment: @user1017524 Depends on what you actually mean exactly. If you want to increment the index, then you should write `listBox1.SelectedIndex += 1`.

Comment: If you have two items in your list and remove one, then the SelectedIndex can only be 0, not 1. And yes, you should change your code to listBox11.SelectedIndex = 1; if you want to set it to a specific value. But it dependeds on what you want to achieve with your code.

Comment: @user1017524 please add the solution as a new answer then accept it. **Don't leave it as part of the question**, after you post answer edit your question and remove it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to test if the item which you are trying to select acutally exists.

```
int index = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index);
If (index < listBox1.Items.Count) {
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = index; 
}
```

---

EDIT: If you want to delete items in a loop, it is a good idea to start at the end, since removing an item changes the position of the following items. Looping upwards would make you skip an item each time you remove an item.

```
for (int i = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (listBox1.Items[i].ToString() == "whatever") {
        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more at the OP, but the code here will function differently depending on whether the selected item is above or below the deleted item.  If the deleted item is before the selected item then keeping the index the same will select the next item, if not, then the code here will work as the OP probably intends.

Comment: You'll also likely want to think about how you handle the error condition.  Do you want to select nothing?  The previous selection?  The last item?  The first item?

Comment: The OP talks about iterating. This might be misleading. He might not want to do a loop at all, but instead just select the next item. In this case, the index of the item to select will remain the same as the index of the removed item, as the next item will take the place of the removed item.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to see the full code sample (with the if statement) to know for sure. But it is pretty obvious you are setting the selected item to an index that isn't in the list box.

Be careful, the selectedIndex is zero based, not one based.

MSDN says of your error:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The assigned value is less than -1 or
>   greater than or equal to the item count.

Since the error indicates it is happening when you set the SelectedIndex to 1, I am assuming that you only have a single item in the listbox (index=0) when this code is called.

Comment: he doesn't increment the index, he is just setting it to 1. But yes, it's outside the range

Comment: @JohnFx I actually have two items in the listBox

Comment: But you are removing one of them in the line before it, meaning the highest index would be 0

Answer (score 0):

Since indices are 0-based, setting `SelectedIndex` to 1 is selecting the *second* value in the list.   I'm guessing it's failing when you have removed all but one of the values and are trying to set `SelectedIndex` to the second one.

Comment: When I remove the code to remove the selected item and keep the one to iterate down to the next item I still get the same error

Comment: If you're trying to iterate I think you have the syntax wrong.  Do you mean `listBox1.SelectedIndex += 1;`?  That is effectively `listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1;`

Answer (score -15):

Do you want to select the first item in the listBox?  If so the code would be:

```
if(listBox1.Items.Count > 0) listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: I was testing it with two items but there will be more items I dont need it to go to the first item